# Popover for Twitter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the popover feature that is included in bootstrap which Twitter has provided. I have been trying to make it work for a while now and am totally burnt out of ideas on making it work, here is a sample of what I currently have for it http://jsfiddle.net/JPf9y/1

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="btn-primary" rel="popover" data-original-title="title" data-content="content">popover</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("a[rel=popover]").popover();
```

It won't work when I click it, I checked to make sure my directory is written correctly.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the bootstrap javascript, bootstrap css, and jQuery javascript in your page.  They can be downloaded here:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/bootstrap.zip
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

For the JSFiddle you can include jQuery under the `Frameworks and Extensions` menu on the left and other files, such as bootstrap's js and css, using the `External Resources` tag on the left side.  For your fiddle I referenced the `.js` and `.css` files from http://cdnjs.com/.

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JPf9y/3/)

Comment: Sorry about that, they are included in my source code, one moment as I update jsfiddle